# how to disable a combo box based on a enumeration list

Tags: wpf, combobox, enums

I have a wpf app c#.

I have a combo box which is populate by an enumeration.

I wish, for instance to disable the 1st or 3rd (etc) item.

This is my markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboJobStatus" />
```

my enum:

```
public enum enJobStatus
{
    Draft = 0,
    Booked = 1,
    Started = 2,
    OnHold = 3,
    Completed = 4,
    Paid = 5,
    All = 6
}
```

my code:

cboJobStatus.ItemsSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(enJobStatus));

my pathetic attempt to get this working:

```
foreach (var item in cboJobStatus.Items)
{
    ((ComboBoxItem)item).IsEnabled = false;
}
```

which did not work and errored at run time because the item is a string and not a combo item.

Comment: create custom `ItemContainerStyle` for `ComboBoxItem` and bind `IsEnabled` to something you want via converter you want

Comment: hi, thanks. do you have an example u could post?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did not work as each item is a string that represents name of `enJobStatus` but, as mentioned in the comment, you can create custom `ItemsContainerStyle` for `ComboBoxItem` and bind `IsEnabled` to your current `DataContext` (in your case string value) via custom `IValueConverter`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboJobStatus">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnabledConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

and in converter you decide which values you want to disable/enable

```
public class EnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (string)value == "Draft";
    }

    //removed content
}
```

Given example will enable only *Draft* value but you can also incorporate `ConverterParameter` to make it more customizable and have an option to pass additional parameter into converter